# Django, Ubuntu, Apache, mod_wsgi

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to configure apache with django on Ubuntu 12.04. I'm using mod_wsgi. I used a couple of different tutorials but none of them fully worked for me. Frustrated, I installed nginx without removing Apache. Tried configuring nginx. Failed. Removed nginx. Now I'm back to trying to configure Apache. However, I'm getting this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also if someone has experience configuring Apache with Django and could help me, I would highly appreciate it. If you need the error.log, please let me know and I'll paste it here. I installed Apache as part of the lamp stack in case you are curious.

If someone knows a tutorial that worked for them, please paste the url. I noticed that quite a few of the tutorials that I did are old, while django is a rapidly evolving framework.

Here are the permissions for var/www:

```
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Jun 16 15:43 var
drwxr-xr-x  5 maahd maahd    4096 May 29 14:20 www

-rwxr-xr-x 1 maahd maahd  580 Mar 27 17:01 ajax.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 maahd maahd  177 Feb 15 05:08 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 maahd maahd 4096 Apr 24 12:35 phploginsession
-rwxr-xr-x 1 maahd maahd 1356 Apr 21 14:24 sftp-config.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 maahd maahd   18 Mar 12 14:03 test1.php
drwxr-xr-x 5 maahd maahd 4096 Apr 22 13:49 upload
```

Contents of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
ServerName localhost
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sp-django-master/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/sp-django-master/

<Directory /var/www/sp-django-master/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Update: I get this error when I try to restart server:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                         /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
[Tue Jun 17 00:09:53 2014] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
[Tue Jun 17 00:09:53 2014] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Output of lsof -i -P -n | grep 80

```
ubuntu-ge 2603 maahd   12u  IPv4  17608      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:48144->91.189.94.25:80 (CLOSE_WAIT)
chrome    2608 maahd   14u  IPv4  54104      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:42019->198.252.206.24:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd   89u  IPv4  52215      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:36980->174.132.123.98:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  101u  IPv4  40423      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:46129->82.148.98.157:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  125u  IPv4  38434      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:42661->95.172.94.14:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  127u  IPv4  55498      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37574->198.252.206.140:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  135u  IPv4  38439      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:58174->212.77.199.218:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  142u  IPv4  52860      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:36982->174.132.123.98:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  143u  IPv4  54393      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:39455->54.230.158.198:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  144u  IPv4  37728      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:59387->23.21.122.50:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  151u  IPv4  56723      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:53436->69.167.156.26:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  153u  IPv4  52863      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:36983->174.132.123.98:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  156u  IPv4  40510      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:59386->23.21.122.50:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  158u  IPv4  52866      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:36984->174.132.123.98:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  163u  IPv4  53439      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:36985->174.132.123.98:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  180u  IPv4  56642      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:60257->204.154.111.229:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  190u  IPv4  54527      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:53437->69.167.156.26:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  191u  IPv4  54530      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:53438->69.167.156.26:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  196u  IPv4  53442      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:36986->174.132.123.98:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  197u  IPv4  54972      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:60821->174.129.25.157:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  198u  IPv4  56691      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:60510->103.245.222.184:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  200u  IPv4  53283      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:46474->103.31.6.34:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  202u  IPv4  54505      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:36913->198.252.206.17:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  203u  IPv4  53458      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:51691->173.194.35.121:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  206u  IPv4  54119      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37694->198.252.206.140:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  207u  IPv4  54533      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:53439->69.167.156.26:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  208u  IPv4  54536      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:53440->69.167.156.26:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  212u  IPv4  54539      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:53441->69.167.156.26:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  219u  IPv4  53459      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:48985->173.194.70.95:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  222u  IPv4  50654      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:42184->173.194.39.45:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  224u  IPv4  56733      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:40622->69.167.143.172:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  225u  IPv4  56738      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55693->69.167.156.17:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  229u  IPv4  55297      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:53901->173.194.70.121:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  230u  IPv4  55298      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56802->185.31.19.192:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  233u  IPv4  54317      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55758->82.148.102.4:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  234u  IPv4  52224      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55410->212.77.199.224:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  235u  IPv4  52878      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:48986->173.194.70.95:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  236u  IPv4  56734      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:40623->69.167.143.172:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  238u  IPv4  55302      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57066->173.194.70.156:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  241u  IPv4  52920      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:32969->184.26.200.117:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  242u  IPv4  53479      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:47444->173.194.39.57:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  244u  IPv4  52932      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37250->54.229.19.41:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  245u  IPv4  52933      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37251->54.229.19.41:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  246u  IPv4  55312      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:33604->72.14.248.34:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  247u  IPv4  53491      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:35331->46.137.72.128:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  248u  IPv4  55319      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:35120->173.194.39.60:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  249u  IPv4  55323      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:53178->68.67.176.5:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  250u  IPv4  55324      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:52934->173.194.35.122:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  253u  IPv4  53495      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:33537->23.209.148.46:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  254u  IPv4  53497      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55903->68.67.176.7:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  256u  IPv4  54707      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:34135->207.241.148.80:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  257u  IPv4  54710      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56075->207.241.148.91:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  258u  IPv4  55335      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:40919->176.34.138.156:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  259u  IPv4  55603      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37944->23.57.207.139:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  260u  IPv4  55392      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:60212->204.154.111.229:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  261u  IPv4  53523      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57086->173.194.35.123:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  263u  IPv4  55796      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:49590->173.194.36.30:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  266u  IPv4  56465      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:60215->204.11.109.63:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  267u  IPv4  53535      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:60216->204.11.109.63:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  268u  IPv4  54606      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:46405->72.32.216.176:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  269u  IPv4  54368      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:60217->204.11.109.63:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  270u  IPv4  54345      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:52943->173.194.35.122:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  271u  IPv4  54715      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:41601->212.77.199.209:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  272u  IPv4  54711      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56076->207.241.148.91:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  274u  IPv4  55419      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:45195->54.225.240.90:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  275u  IPv4  54394      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37274->54.229.19.41:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  277u  IPv4  54712      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56077->207.241.148.91:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  278u  IPv4  54395      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37275->54.229.19.41:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  279u  IPv4  54398      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37276->54.229.19.41:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  280u  IPv4  54401      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37277->54.229.19.41:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  281u  IPv4  53609      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55790->82.148.102.4:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  282u  IPv4  53612      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55791->82.148.102.4:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  284u  IPv4  56536      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:43291->173.192.220.64:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  285u  IPv4  56538      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:36253->67.217.177.158:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  286u  IPv4  56537      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:33714->54.255.156.221:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  287u  IPv4  55426      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:49253->12.129.199.106:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  288u  IPv4  55428      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:53623->54.246.112.221:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  289u  IPv4  54409      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:54767->54.225.133.14:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  290u  IPv4  54408      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:52682->138.108.6.20:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  291u  IPv4  55430      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:42689->82.148.117.35:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  292u  IPv4  56566      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:35605->212.77.199.225:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  293u  IPv4  54713      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56078->207.241.148.91:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  294u  IPv4  54419      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:35504->67.217.177.164:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  295u  IPv4  54426      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:48218->79.125.12.28:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  296u  IPv4  56616      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:51809->50.19.233.13:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  297u  IPv4  53649      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56653->176.32.100.68:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  298u  IPv4  53657      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:50796->54.197.240.229:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  300u  IPv4  56604      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:42187->204.2.197.204:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  301u  IPv4  56605      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57379->103.15.158.208:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  302u  IPv4  56602      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57663->216.151.217.153:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  303u  IPv4  56603      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:47493->173.194.39.57:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  304u  IPv4  55452      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55995->8.30.11.13:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  305u  IPv4  56606      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:36411->74.121.141.85:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  306u  IPv4  53669      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:45043->173.193.208.135:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  307u  IPv4  55457      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:45041->173.193.208.135:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  308u  IPv4  54611      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:51100->173.194.35.124:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  309u  IPv4  56622      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:45044->173.193.208.135:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  310u  IPv4  55462      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:45045->173.193.208.135:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  312u  IPv4  54714      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56079->207.241.148.91:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  318u  IPv4  56879      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:34118->54.230.44.48:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  319u  IPv4  56870      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:33321->124.155.223.9:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  320u  IPv4  54721      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:47567->198.232.124.97:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  323u  IPv4  54726      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57200->173.194.70.156:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  324u  IPv4  54618      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:58544->68.232.35.139:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  326u  IPv4  56185      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:42469->173.194.70.120:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  331u  IPv4  53899      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57801->173.194.39.58:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  334u  IPv4  53904      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:35261->209.114.44.42:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  335u  IPv4  55754      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:52672->198.41.191.38:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  336u  IPv4  55755      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:38502->50.17.239.15:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  337u  IPv4  53915      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:38503->50.17.239.15:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  338u  IPv4  53919      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56606->68.67.176.10:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  339u  IPv4  54691      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:38505->50.17.239.15:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  340u  IPv4  54694      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56608->68.67.176.10:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  341u  IPv4  55761      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:38507->50.17.239.15:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  342u  IPv4  55764      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56610->68.67.176.10:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  343u  IPv4  55767      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:38509->50.17.239.15:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  344u  IPv4  55770      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56612->68.67.176.10:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  345u  IPv4  56904      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:38511->50.17.239.15:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  346u  IPv4  56909      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56614->68.67.176.10:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  350u  IPv4  53956      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56098->207.241.148.91:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  351u  IPv4  53957      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56099->207.241.148.91:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  352u  IPv4  54733      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:56100->207.241.148.91:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  353u  IPv4  54742      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:58587->212.77.199.218:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  354u  IPv4  54776      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:33485->23.50.80.143:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  357u  IPv4  53988      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55974->54.86.224.50:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  358u  IPv4  57033      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:47468->71.19.242.237:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  360u  IPv4  55863      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55570->212.77.199.224:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  361u  IPv4  55865      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57307->94.100.23.179:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  362u  IPv4  55864      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:55571->212.77.199.224:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  363u  IPv4  55866      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57308->94.100.23.179:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  364u  IPv4  55867      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57309->94.100.23.179:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  365u  IPv4  55868      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57310->94.100.23.179:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  366u  IPv4  55885      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57801->8.39.37.21:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  367u  IPv4  57077      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:57802->8.39.37.21:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  368u  IPv4  54018      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:37895->82.199.80.141:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  369u  IPv4  54017      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:42423->173.194.39.45:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  370u  IPv4  54781      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:49062->54.228.249.4:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  371u  IPv4  54026      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:35730->212.77.199.225:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  373u  IPv4  54028      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:40050->212.77.199.208:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  374u  IPv4  54033      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:43144->69.25.24.26:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  378u  IPv4  54041      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:39493->8.39.37.25:80 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    2608 maahd  379u  IPv4  54046      0t0  TCP 10.27.168.45:43429->71.19.244.184:80 (ESTABLISHED)
```

thanks

Comment: There should be an error in the log when that 403 happens.  Can you also provide the relevant config (probably the virtual host)?

Comment: [Mon Jun 16 23:33:45 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Mon Jun 16 23:33:45 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied

Comment: What do the permissions look like on the configured document root? (`ls -la`)

Comment: Can you edit that output into your question?  I assume that means `/var/www` is your document root, right?  Can you please provide the config of the virtual host?

Comment: I added the output into my question. /var/www is the server root directory for the lamp stack. I'm not really sure what will be the server root once I'm done configuring django. But my php websites were running out of /var/www. I'm not sure what you mean by config of the virtual host since I'm a newbie. However, I added contents of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content is trying to run out of `/home/maahd/development/django/sp-django-master`, for which the user Apache is running as (`www-data` by default on Ubuntu) does not have access.

Most likely it can't even traverse into your user's home directory, you should probably move that directory somewhere that it can access (and reconfigure accordingly) instead of mangling your home directory's permissions.

Comment: Okay. So I moved my django web app folder to /var/www. Here are the permissions: drwxrwxr-x 6 maahd maahd 4096 Jun 15 13:50 sp-django-master. I also reconfigured httpd.conf which I updated above in the question. Still getting the 403 error. Furthermore, I cannot restart my server. It gives an error that I have included in the question above.

Comment: @maahd You have something else bound on port 80, possibly an old Apache process that hasn't stopped.  Stop Apache then run `lsof -i -P -n | grep 80` - what's listening on that port?

Comment: I remember I configured nginx to listen on port 80. Shouldn't have installed one server on top of another. Big mistake. I've pasted output from lsof -i -P -n | grep 80 above in the question. It's really long so I apologize for that but I couldn't make much sense of it.

Comment: @maahd Can Apache start successfully once nginx has been stopped?

Comment: I uninstalled nginx some time ago (before posting this question). I was also having a tough time stopping apache so killed it. Now I just tried to start it and it worked! Furthermore, it is giving me Django database error which is really good news. The server is successfully communicating with/loading the django app with error traceback :). Now all I need to do it configure my DB. Thanks a lot for your help. I really really appreciate it!

Comment: @maahd No problem!